# Transforming this exponential function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

*Here's the problem:*

> A biologist places agar, a gel made from
>   seaweed, in a Petri dish and infects it with
>   bacteria. She uses the measurement of
>   the growth ring to estimate the number of
>   bacteria present. The biologist finds that
>   the bacteria increase in population at an
>   exponential rate of $20%$ every $2$ days.
>
> a) If the culture starts with a population
>   of $5000$ bacteria, what is the
>   transformed exponential function in
>   the form $P = a(c)^{bx}$ that represents the
>   population, $P$, of the bacteria over time,
>   $x$, in days?

My problem is creating the exponential function.

What I did so far is $P = 5000(0.20)^{???x}$

Where $5000$ is the starting population, $0.20$ is the exponential rate, and I'm not sure how to transform the $x$ so that I could get a rate of "every $2$ days."

The textbook had an answer of:

> $P = 5000(1.2)^{\frac{1}{2}x}$

*I wanna understand how I could get this answer.*

Why is the constant $1.2$? I'm assuming they added a $1$ for the first day of growth; but why would they do that?

Also, how is "every $2$ days" modeled by multiplying $x$ by $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You speak about an increase : $1$ being the initiel value and $0.2$ the increase every two days, then, after two days you have $1+0.2=1.2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $P(0) = 5000$, so if the form is $P = a(c)^{bx}$ then $5000 = a(c)^{b*0} = a$. Then we know that $\frac{P(x+2)}{P(x)} = 1.2$, so $\frac{5000c^{b(x+2)}}{5000c^{bx}} = 1.2$ which yields $c^{2b} = 1.2$. At this point, let $c > 1$ be whatever you want and calculate $b$. In this case, we can let $c=1.2$ since that's the rate that the problem provided. Then $b$ must be $\frac{1}{2}$.

The intuition is as you said, since the rate of growth is $.2$ for every two years, then if that's the rate of growth we choose for $c$, then $b$ must be halved to account for that, as $x$ would be growing "two times as fast". $c$ also must be greater than $1$, as the growth rate adds on top of what was there before.

Comment: How does $\frac {P(x+2)}{P(x)} = .2$ yield $c^{2b} = 1.2?$

Comment: Whoops, I meant 1.2 there.